# How to apply inline styles using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to give some styles using jquery. when I load some popup pages in my website.

I tried like this.

```
$("#myCountDiv").css({ "bottom":"298","position":"relative"});

$("#myInnerContainer").css({"margin-top:35"});
```

Both are not working. Please help me. How can I applay these styles to those divs?

Thanks

Comment: You can invoke them after the HTML is loaded.

Comment: @learner if you are using jqueryUI dialogs then you can set all these attributes while initializing your dialog

Comment: $("#myCountDiv").css({ 'color':'red','position':'relative'});//check this code its working fine man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first example isn't working because "bottom" should be "298px" and the bottom example isn't working because the property needs to be the key and "35" should be "35px".

**Examples:**

```
$("#myCountDiv").css({bottom: '298px', position: 'relative'});
$("#myInnerContainer").css({marginTop: '35px'});
```

Have a look at the more examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

I always get confused also with that .css() property, there are just too many options and each has their own rule.

Instead of confusing you with all the options, id' recommend just remembering this one.

```
$('div').css({
    'property':'value',
    'bottom':'298x',
    'position':'relative',
    'margin-top':'35px',
});
```

It is just like CSS, but you have to put quotes around the property and the value.  The confusion comes in when you also can use absolute keys, but when you do that, you have to camelback any key that has a hypen:

```
$('div').css({
    bottom:'298x',
    position:'relative',
    marginTop:'35px',
});
```

It's better just to stick with the first way.